# C: Division of two Arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I have two Arrays of type `int`. Each is about 17901 elements long. One represents the altitude, while the other the airspeed. I would like to divide the two arrays (this division will result in the mach number). How would I do this?

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
for (i = 0; i < ((size / 2) + 1); i++) {    // size/2 here is 17901
    machNumber[i] = (ASarray[i] / soundspeed[i]); 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Comment: @AlexandreFenyo I think that this expression  (size/2)+1 is invalid.:) Should it be ( size + 1 ) / 2?

Comment: 1. If `machNumber` is a floating-point array, but `ASarray` and `soundspeed` are both arrays of integers, this code will perform truncating integer addition, which may not be what you want.  2. You should run the loop for I=0, I<N, where N is the size of the arrays. Running the loop up to some weird expression, involving a variable named "size" that's actually about twice the size of the arrays, is an invitation to confusion and bugs.

Comment: What's `size`? And why is your cycle iterating to `(size / 2) + 1` specifically? Where did this expression come from?

Comment: Describe the 3rd, `machNumber[]`  - its type and size.

Answer (score 1):

replace `((size/2)+1` by the computed size `sizeof(ASarray)/sizeof(*ASarray)`

This way, there will be no doubt about the loop. Of course, the size of ASarray must be statically defined (the memory must not have been allocated with malloc).

```
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(ASarray) / sizeof(*ASarray); i++) {
  machNumber[i] = (ASarray[i] / soundspeed[i]);
}
```

Comment: Not seeing the declaration of `ASarray`, you can't be sure it is literally declared as an *array* (as opposed to being a mere pointer). Your `sizeof` trick will not work for a pointer.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this is why I have written *the memory must not have been allocated with malloc*. But since the size is known (17901 elements), this may have been allocated statically.

Comment: I know you know what you're doing, but when you say, "Of course, the size must be statically defined", you're assuming that everyone else understands this well, but that's manifestly *not* true; many beginning programmers don't understand this, and make that very mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Halfing the size does not compute the number of elements correctly: you should instead divide the size of the array by the size of its element (both in bytes). Furthermore, if `machNumber` is a floating point type and neither `ASarray` nor `soundspeed` are, you need a cast to compute the proper Mach value:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ASarray) / sizeof(ASarray[i]); i++) {
    machNumber[i] = (double)ASarray[i] / soundspeed[i]; 
}
```